# MySQL - EAV or XML?

Tags: php, mysql, xml, entity-attribute-value

I'm wondering about solution in my recent project. Site has categories (nested set model) and products. Main problem is that I must implement many categories properties. These properties are different for each category. Of course products which belongs to specific category have specific properties values.

My problem is how to solve storing these properties. I read about EAV model but main con for these solution is basicly slow, needs many additional tables and not suitable for larger data sets. The more I read about it the more I'm not convinced.

My second thought is XML. Categories table would have xml column that keeps properties names and in product table also xml column but with properties values.

Now question - which solution will be better and more flexible? Another problem is to allow user search by specific categories properties. I'm assuming that db would have many products so performance of queries is very important.

Comment: Can you please describe your current model ? It's not very clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Ask yourself which would be more performant when a user wants to search on an attribute value? Arbitrary XML that can't be indexed easily, or an EAV table with indexing?

Comment: Basicly for now I'm searching best suitable model. For example - one of categories is cars, that category would have properties like: color, power, production year, engine type etc. Now products have values of these properties for example: color - red, power 90HP, production year 2010, engine - diesel. Main goal is to creata dynamic serach basing on these properties.

Comment: @Mark Baker I read about creating search query in EAV model and it looks like some kind of nightmare, XML looks easier but I know nothing about performance that query (assuming that I will use extractvalue in where clause)...

Comment: If the XML is stored in a database column, then it's not searchable by index, and can't easily be handled with full text indexing either because you need to distinguish the xml entity structure from the actual data values. ExtractValue gives you that precision, but is a big overhead (and still no indexing) so every search will be a full table scan with the ExtractValue parsing overhead thrown in for good measure

Comment: EAV solutions have their pros and cons, but simple EAV is not nearly as inefficient as the anti-lobby would have you believe; and building the queries is a lot less complex than using xpath against xml data

Comment: So for my case EAV solution will be more suitable? My project will grow with time and I want to start building application where queries are relatively fast and they will not consume all server resources.